# Make a new list depending on group number and add scores up as well

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

If a have a list within a another list that looks like this...

```
[['Harry',9,1],['Harry',17,1],['Jake',4,1], ['Dave',9,2],['Sam',17,2],['Sam',4,2]]
```

How can I add the middle element together so so for 'Harry' for example, it shows up as `['Harry', 26]` and also for Python to look at the group number (3rd element) and output the winner only (the one with the highest score which is the middle element). So for each group, there needs to be one winner. So the final output shows:

```
[['Harry', 26],['Sam',21]]
```

THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE: It has a third element as well which I am stuck about

The similar question gave me an answer of:

```
grouped_scores = {}
for name, score, group_number in players_info:
    if name not in grouped_scores:
        grouped_scores[name] = score
        grouped_scores[group_number] = group_number 
    else:
        grouped_scores[name] += score
```

But that only adds the scores up, it doesn't take out the winner from each group. Please help.

I had thought doing something like this, but I'm not sure exactly what to do...

```
grouped_scores = {}
for name, score, group_number in players_info:
    if name not in grouped_scores:
        grouped_scores[name] = score
    else:
        grouped_scores[name] += score
    for group in group_number:
        if grouped_scores[group_number] = group_number:
            [don't know what to do here]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution:

Use `itertools.groupby`, and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
l=[['Harry',9,1],['Harry',17,1],['Jake',4,1], ['Dave',9,2],['Sam',17,2],['Sam',4,2]]
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
l2=[list(y) for x,y in groupby(l,key=lambda x: x[-1])]
l3=[]
for x in l2:
    d=defaultdict(int)
    for x,y,z in x:
       d[x]+=y
    l3.append(max(list(map(list,dict(d).items())),key=lambda x: x[-1]))
```

Now:

```
print(l3)
```

Is:

```
[['Harry', 26], ['Sam', 21]]
```

## Explanation:

First two lines are importing modules. Then the next line is using `groupby` to separate in to two groups based on last element of each sub-list. Then the next line to create empty list. Then the next loop iterating trough the grouped ones. Then create a `defaultdict`. Then the sub-loop is adding the stuff to the `defaultdict`. Then last line to manage how to make that dictionary into a list.

Comment: Can you please just add in comments so I can learn and understand what each line is doing?

Comment: @Harry First two lines are importing modules, then next line is using `groupby` to separate in to two groups based on last element of each sub-list, next line to create empty list, next loop iterating trough the grouped ones, then create a `defaultdict`, then the sub-loop is adding the stuff to the `defaultdict`, then last line to manage how to make that dictionary into a list.

Comment: @Harry Happy to help, :-), 

Comment: @Harry YW. again. :D

Answer (score 0):

I would aggregate the data first with a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> combined = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> data = [['Harry',9,1],['Harry',17,1],['Jake',4,1], ['Dave',9,2],['Sam',17,2],['Sam',4,2]]
>>> 
>>> for name, score, group in data:
...:    combined[group][name] += score
...:    
>>> combined
>>> 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {1: defaultdict(int, {'Harry': 26, 'Jake': 4}),
             2: defaultdict(int, {'Dave': 9, 'Sam': 21})})
```

Then apply `max` to each value in that dict.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [list(max(v.items(), key=itemgetter(1))) for v in combined.values()]
>>> [['Harry', 26], ['Sam', 21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools.groupby` and then take the middle value from the grouped element and then append it to a list passed on the maximum condition

```
import itertools
l=[['Harry',9,1],['Harry',17,1],['Jake',4,1], ['Dave',9,2],['Sam',17,2],['Sam',4,2]]
maxlist=[]
maxmiddleindexvalue=0
for key,value in itertools.groupby(l,key=lambda x:x[0]):
    s=0
    m=0
    for element in value:
        s+=element[1]
        m=max(m,element[1])
    if(m==maxmiddleindexvalue):
        maxlist.append([(key,s)])

    if(m>maxmiddleindexvalue):
        maxlist=[(key,s)]
        maxmiddleindexvalue=m

print(maxlist)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('Harry', 26), [('Sam', 21)]]
```